# Error in JavaMail when running Selenium

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to extract an email running selenium and maven but I get the following error when trying to connect:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: pop.google.com
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect
```

But when I run the same exact code in a different project without selenium it works, any idea what's causing this?

```
public class EmailService {

    private static String SERVER;
    private static String USER;
    private static String PASSWORD;
    private static final String TEXT_FROM="SMS from";


    /**
     * Constructor to setup imap info
     * @param server email server to connect
     * @param usr email address of user
     * @param passwd password of user
     */
    public EmailService(String server, String usr, String passwd){
        SERVER = server;
        USER = usr;
        PASSWORD = passwd;
    }


    public static String receive(String type, String receiver, Date d) {
        Store store = null;
        Folder folder= null;
        SubjectTerm subject;
        RecipientStringTerm recipient = new RecipientStringTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO,USER);

        try{
            //Get session
            Properties props = new Properties();
            //props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
            props.put("mail.pop3.host", SERVER);
            props.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            props.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            //Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

            //Get  message store and connect
            store = session.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD);

            //Get default folder
            folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
            if(folder == null) throw new Exception("No Default folder");

            //Get Inbox
            folder = folder.getFolder("INBOX");
            if(folder == null) throw new Exception ("No Inbox");

            //Open folder for read only
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: Run locally? did U copied working or rewrite? Did U tried with less or none selenium jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no host named "pop.google.com".  Maybe you meant "pop.gmail.com"?

It probably works on some machines because of the [first common mistake described in this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: wow I've been stuck for over a week with this problem and that solved it! It was working as "pop.google.com" in my other project but changing it to "pop.gmail.com" worked thank you so much!

Comment: You probably could've used pop.nosuchhost.com and it still would've worked because of that common mistake.  It's completely ignoring the properties you pass in.